vmailmgr vadduser password hashing
the vmailmgr command "vadduser" uses obviously a salted hash to store the password. But I cannot reproduce it to know how exactly it works. For example, for the password "test" I get those two example entries:

$1$BZBVNUbG$PSkIKTT5Fss1ve.b2LM/N1
$1$KOX0Xf2q$WV4EJy5M7KnhbciYqbqT70

So it looks to me, the part KOX0Xf2q and BZBVNUbG is a salt, but how is the salt combined with the password and how is it hashed?

I got it myself, its md5/DES and I can reproduce it with openssl passwd -1 -salt SALT PASSWORD
